# Textview inside Fragment and fragment inside activity

Tags: fragment

I have some something to ask. I have a textview inside a fragment, the fragment inside an activity and I want text changed when clicking a button in my fragment. How can I do that ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the TextView through the view id for your TextView that is within your fragments layout file. Then on your onclick listener for the button, update the text for that TextView.